# What is the difference between "what is going on with you" and "what is going on for you"?

Tags: prepositions, difference, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between *go on with* someone and *go on for* *someone*. For example:

> You are so pale! What is going on **with**/**for** you.

I though that the correct preposition was *with* when used with *go on* in the sense of something  happening to someone. But in this [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/platonic-love/202001/how-open-conflict-benefits-relationships) they used *for*. Here is the excerpt:

> After you share your world, and what upset you, welcome the other person to share their side of the story. You might say something like, "I wanted to give you a chance to also share what might have been **going on** **for** you in that moment."

Does *go on for* someone means the same as *go on with* or it means something else in the context?

Comment: _Going on_ here means _happening_, as you say, so _what has been going on for you_ = what has happened recently that affects you. I don't think there is a fixed rule as to which preposition to use.